# Powershell GCI Workflow - Is Nested Foreach Parallel Possible? Dangers?

Tags: powershell, foreach, parallel-processing, workflow, get-childitem

I have a workflow that I created that recursively scans hundreds of file shares for specific file names/extensions. Everything works great, but I'm wondering if there is a way to improve it's speed.

In the foreach -parallel, I'm getting child items and ACL recursively from a list of shares, 20 at a time. What I'm wondering is if there is a way to also make it process in parallel within the GCI.

In other words, is foreach -parallel nesting possible/doable, and if so can you offer suggestions such as syntax, the dangers of doing it, etc. I've found very little documentation on it and am hoping for some expert advice

If that doesn't make sense, here's a different way to explain it. I have 5 shares that I'm searching recursively, all with different sizes and a different number of files:

\share1\folder1  Size: 5GB

\share2\folder1  Size: 79GB

\share3\folder1  Size: 2GB

\share4\folder1  Size: 8GB

\share5\folder1 Size: 103GB

The GCI will process all 5 at the same time, however share2 and share5 are going to take a LOT more time than the others due to their size. Is there a way to to make a script process all 5 shares in parallel, and also process multiple files at once within the GCI? So it would start searching all 20 shares at once, and get information on say 5 files within the share at a time?

Here's a piece of what I'm doing, shortened down a bit for length reasons with variable names/input changed. I'm sure there are things that I can improve upon in here as well, but overall it works.

```
workflow Scan-Shares
{
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [int]$ThrottleLimit = 20
    )

        $File1 = Import-csv C:\Drives.csv
        $ExtList = @((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "www.websitewithfilenames.com").content | convertfrom-json | % {$_.filters})

        foreach -parallel -throttlelimit $throttlelimit ($Line in $File1)
            {
                inlinescript
                {
                 $Line=$using:Line
                 $Extlist=$using:Extlist
                 $Path = $Line.Path + '\*'
                 $Directory = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse  -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue  | select-object   name, Extension, FullName, LastWriteTime, Directory -ExpandProperty Name

                 $singleRegex = ($extlist | %{ '^' + $_ + '$' }) -join '|'

                 [array]$Files = $Directory -match $singleRegex

                    if($files.count -gt 0 )
                    {
                        foreach($SingleFile in $Files)
                        {

                         $Owner = (Get-Acl $FullName -Erroraction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue).Owner 
                         New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
                                        Path = $File.Fullname
                                        Filename = $File.Name
                                        LastWriteTime = $File.LastWriteTime
                                        Owner = $Owner
                                        Directory = $File.Directory } |
                                      Export-Csv -Force C:\Share-Results.CSV -Append
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

}

Comment: For trivial tasks runspaces will be much more efficient than a workflow.